# Flutter Driver - Does not locate Flutter AlertDialog and its elements

Tags: flutter-alertdialog, flutterdriver

I have a Flutter `AlertDiaog` that comes up on my **flutter** app.
Using **Flutter Driver**, I am unable to tap on either the Flutter AlertDialog or on any element on the AlertDialog.
Is there a way to tap on any AlertDialog that comes up on my app?

I have tried all the below, but still no luck:

1. First:

```
    await driver.tap(find.byType('ModalBarrier'));
    print('*******TAPPED - ModalBarrier*******');
```

2. Second

```
    await driver.tap(find.byType('AlertDialog'));
    print('*******TAPPED - AlertDialog*******');
```

3. Third

```
     await driver.tap(find.text('Gallery')); // Tapping 'Gallery', can access pics
     print('*******TAPPED - Gallery *******');
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to first identify the text in `AlertDialog` by a unique key, tell the driver about it and then perform `tap` action on it. In your main code, add `key` property to parent widget that has the `Text` you want to tap on, for example: I am showing a simple `AlertDialog` that show 2 options, as below:

[image]

The code for this is:

```
showDialog(context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ListBody(
                children: <Widget>[
                  GestureDetector(
                    key: Key('firstOptionKey'),
                    child: Text('Take a picture'),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    key: Key('secondOptionKey'),
                    child: Text('Select from gallery'),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
```

As you can see, I've wrapped both the text with `GestureDetector` that allows us to tap on them. Also, I used `key` property for each `GestureDetector` to uniquely identify both texts.

In your driver test, you then simply need to identify each text using `byValueKey` and tell driver to tap on it, as below:

```
test('test dialog', () async {

          final firstText = find.byValueKey('firstOptionKey');
          await driver.waitFor(find.text('Tap'));  
          await driver.tap(find.text('Tap'));   // tap on this button to open alertDialog
          await driver.waitFor(firstText);      // wait for flutter driver to locate and identify the element on screen
          await driver.tap(firstText);
          print('tapped on it');
        });
```

[image]

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Darshan, 
Thanks for your response.
In your main code above I see that you have not used 'return' while calling showDialog(). Are you able to return the photo gallery on screen if you add such an action under tap{} ?
For me flutter driver could not locate the AlertDialog till now only because I am using 'return' for showDialog() call, such that the photo gallery is actually returned after tap.

Comment: I tried based on your reply and directly returned `alertDialog` on `onPressed` method and it works as expected.

Comment: The solution worked me only after I used the runUnsynchronized method, like this:       await driver.runUnsynchronized(() async {
    await driver.tap(find.byValueKey('firstOptionKey'));
  });